# Как из .py сделать .exe?

Tags: python, exe

Итак,я хочу из файла .py сделать .exe,но на версии 3.8.5(последняя),установить его я не могу(вроде поддержка прекратилась дальше 3.7,либо что-то не так у меня).
Как сейчас сделать из py в exe?

Ошибка:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'd:\pythoninstalling\python.exe' 'C:\Users\Компьютер\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\4D2B~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpr7hey5ho'
     cwd: C:\Users\Компьютер\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ndw6svlx\pyinstaller
Complete output (38 lines):
running dist_info
creating C:\Users\Компьютер\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-j3x4m8jz\pyinstaller.egg-info
writing C:\Users\Компьютер\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-j3x4m8jz\pyinstaller.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to C:\Users\Компьютер\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-j3x4m8jz\pyinstaller.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing entry points to C:\Users\Компьютер\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-j3x4m8jz\pyinstaller.egg-info\entry_points.txt
writing requirements to C:\Users\Компьютер\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-j3x4m8jz\pyinstaller.egg-info\requires.txt
writing top-level names to C:\Users\Компьютер\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-j3x4m8jz\pyinstaller.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing manifest file 'C:\Users\Компьютер\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-j3x4m8jz\pyinstaller.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest file 'C:\Users\Компьютер\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-j3x4m8jz\pyinstaller.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xca in position 0: invalid continuation byte (sitecustomize.py, line 21)
warning: no files found matching 'pyinstaller-gui.py'
no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\build'
no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\.waf-*'
no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\.waf3-*'
no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\waf-*'
no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\waf3-*'
no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\_sdks'
no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\.vagrant'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'bootloader\.lock-waf*'
no previously-included directories found matching 'doc\source'
no previously-included directories found matching 'doc\_build'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.tmp' found under directory 'doc'
warning: no files found matching 'news\_template.rst'
no previously-included directories found matching 'news'
no previously-included directories found matching 'old'
no previously-included directories found matching 'scripts'
no previously-included directories found matching 'tests\scripts'
no previously-included directories found matching '.github'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.*'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '*.yml'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '*~'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.directory'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.py[co]' found anywhere in distribution
writing manifest file 'C:\Users\Компьютер\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-j3x4m8jz\pyinstaller.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
creating 'C:\Users\Компьютер\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-j3x4m8jz\pyinstaller.dist-info'
error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'
----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'd:\pythoninstalling\python.exe' 'C:\Users\Компьютер\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip_vendor\pep517_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\4D2B~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpr7hey5ho' Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112908/discussion-on-question-by-4-xun---py--exe).

Answer (score 1):

Используйте библиотеку `pyinstaller`, а именно

`pyinstaller myfile.py --onefile` если консольное

`pyinstaller myfile.py --onefile --windowed` если не консольное

Comment: Я пытался установить pyinstaller,но появляется ошибка...

Comment: Какая ошибка?..

Comment: @4xun Пишите в вопросе что за ошибка. Других вариантов всё-равно не будет кроме pyinstaller, но и с ним не всё может взлететь

Comment: ошибку добавил.

Answer (score 1):

Если есть проблема со сменой версии на ниже, вот руководство:

Узнаём расположение нашего Python (в пуске ищем папку Python, кликаем ПКМ по ней, нажимаем на пункт "Расположение файла", дальше, если видим ярлыки вместо папок и файлов питона, нажимаем ПКМ по ярлыку, и жмём "Расположение файла", так мы оказались в директории питона), переходим в папку Scripts, копируем путь к ней. Далее с помощью поиска, пишем ключевые слова: переменных сред, нажимаем на Изменение системных переменных среды. Нажимаем на кнопку "Переменные среды...". Выбираем переменную "PATH" и нажимаем "Изменить". Нажимаем на кнопку "Создать" и вставляем путь к папке Scripts, скопированный нами ранее. Сохраняем это всё, выходим из окон. Перезапускаем cmd, вуаля!

Позаимствованное видео по заданному вопросу:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CgCJwDjm_Cw

Описание:

Пару команд для корректной работы:

```
pip install wheel
```

```
python -m pip install pyinstaller
```

1. Для того чтобы вся операция произошла корректно, нужно в начале перейти в директорию с файлом, из которого Вы хотите сделать **.exe**. Всё это нужно делать в консоли Windows, как и описано в видео.
2. Есть пару команд под нужды пользователя:

```
pyinstaller -F main.py
```

В этом варианте мы скомпилировали программу в единую, но **pyinstaller** подставил свою иконку программе и чтобы это изменить нужно добавить к команде выше некоторые корректировки:

```
pyinstaller -F -i "Путь к нашей иконке формата .icо в двойных кавычках" main.py
```

Таким образом мы компилируем программу с выбранной нами иконкой.

- Параметр **-i** означает добавление в программу иконки;
- **main.py** в данном случае обозначает тот файл, который мы хотим переделать.

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: либо дополняйте ответ, либо удалите его и оставьте комментарий под вопросом.